# Understanding static class variables across processes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, static, multiprocessing

I was creating different daemon workers with the same class as their target using `multiprocessing` module. This class import different modules dynamically based on the context and storing those modules in the class scoped static dictionary. I was started thinking, due to class level static dictionary, will all the imports made by all past workers (which might be already terminated) be available/present in all future workers?

So I debugged and realized that this was not happening indeed and imports by past workers were not present future worker, as desired. But started wondering why so. So I created small example imitating the same. Below are two examples. Both involve same `Cmodule.py` which contains the worker's target class `C`. The difference is just in `temp.py`, that too, only in argument of `mup.Process()`. First example fails, in the sense that member of the static dict in class `C` added by past worker is present in future worker. While this is not the case with second example.

**Cmodule.py**

```
class C:
    staticDict = {}

    def __init__(self, condition):
        if condition:
            C.staticDict['a'] = 'a'
        else:
            C.staticDict['b'] = 'b'
        self.printStaticDict()

    def printStaticDict(self):
        print(C.staticDict)
```

**Example 1 - temp.py**

```
import multiprocessing as mup
from Cmodule import *

def newProc3():
    c = C(True)

def newProc4():
    c = C(False)

newProc3Obj = mup.Process(newProc3())
newProc4Obj = mup.Process(newProc4())
newProc3Obj.start()
newProc4Obj.start()
```

**Example 2 - temp.py**

```
import multiprocessing as mup
from Cmodule import *

def newProc3():
    c = C(True)

def newProc4():
    c = C(False)

newProc3Obj = mup.Process(target=newProc3)  //this differs from example 1
newProc4Obj = mup.Process(target=newProc4)  //this differs from example 1
newProc3Obj.start()
newProc4Obj.start()
```

**Example 1 - output**

```
{'a': 'a'}
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
```

**Example 2 - output**

```
{'a': 'a'}
{'b': 'b'}
```

Note that in example 1 output, key value `'a':'a'` is retained in second worker, but that is not the case in example 2. So, what is the difference between below two?

```
newProc4Obj = mup.Process(newProc4())
```

and

```
newProc4Obj = mup.Process(target=newProc4)
```

Also is it ok what I am trying to do as explained in the first paragraph of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two big - and quite obvious - differences between your two versions actually.

In the first example, you are calling `newProc3` and `newProc4` and passing the *results* of those calls - in this case, `None` - as the `group` argument of `Process`.

In the second example, you are passing the `newProc3` / `newProc4` *functions* as the `target` argument.

This means that in the first case, your `newProcX` functions are both executed in the parent process, which is why you **seem** to get the expected result - but actually you don't : the `Process` don't have a target so they don't execute anything at all.

The second example is the correct way to setup a Process - by passing it a callable as target - but since those are different processes, the parent's process `C.staticDict` is not impacted.

If you want to share data between processes, you have to use a `Queue` as [explained in the fine manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).